# Need to arrange data from table in a pivoted format

Tags: t-sql, pivot, row, rank

I have the data in the following format in TABLE 1.Need help in creating a query

Table 1

```
            Type  Currency    Value
            -AX     AU        35
            -AX     BR        98
            -AX     CA        18
            -AX     CH        1.
            -AX     EU        69
            -AX     GB        70
            -AX     HU        1.
            -AX     IL        62
            -AX     IN        23
            -AX     JP        29
            -AX     KR        5.
            -AX     MX        68
            -AX     NO        77
            -AX     NZ        75
            -AX     PL        6.
            -AX     RU        2
            -AX     SE        59
            -AX     SG        90
            -AX     TR        57
            -AX     TW        4.
            -AX     US        32
            -AX     ZA        62
            AUT     AU        0.
            AUT     CA        .2
            AUT     EU        .6
            AUT     GB        9.
            AUT     HK        .6
            AUT     JP        .4
            AUT     KR        3.
            AUT     MX        .8
            AUT     MY        56
            AUT     SE        .0
            AUT     TH        .0
            AUT     TR        .4
            AUT     US        53
            AUT     ZA        .8
            AYT     BR        3.
            AYT     CH        29
            AYT     HK        65
            AYT     IL        57
            AYT     PL        .7
            AYT     TR        8.
            AYT     US        .1
```

Need to do the following

1) get the factor from table2 -- For Eg factor retrieved is 2

Eg: Select factor from table2 and divide every value in above table with 23

2) After I change the values display in the below format

```
            CCY        AX      AUT       AYT        TOTAL      
            AU         1        1        1          3   
            BR         -        -        3          3
            CA         3        3        3          9
            CH         -        2        -          2
            EU         3        3        3          9
            GB         -        3        3
            HK                           
            HU         2        2        2          6
            IL         11       -        -          11
            IN         8        8        8          24
            JP         6        6        6          18
            KR         0        0        0          0
            MX         -        0        -          0
            MY          9        -       -          9
            NO         1        -        -
            NZ         1        1        1
            PL         3        3        3
            SE         -        -        -
            SG         -        5        5
            TH                           
            TR         2        2        2
            TW         1        1        1
            ZA         4        4        4
```

The numbers above are for representation purpose only.Any help .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT`, like this.

```
SELECT
    [Currency] AS 'CCY',
    [AX],
    [AUT],
    [AYT],
    ISNULL([AX], 0) +
        ISNULL([AUT], 0) +
        ISNULL([AYT], 0) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM [Table1]
PIVOT (
    SUM([Value])
    FOR [Type] IN ([AX], [AUT], [AYT])
) AS [P]
```